# TeamCity BuildAgent does not see the network drive

Tags: powershell, teamcity, build-agent

I want to copy the file to a network drive using build agent (powershell or cmd (Build Steps)).

```
P:
# or
cd P:\foolder\
# ...
```

But the commands don't work. Build log: "Disk P not found".
The disk is connected via windows. When running from windows, the commands work.
I assume java/BuildAgent doesn't have rights. But my user has rights. And java, and BuildAgent runs under my user.

Please, do not offer FTP

Comment: Have you tried using UNC instead? `\\yourServer\share\foolder`

Comment: @ManuelBatsching buildagent runs under my user and should see network drives. In fact, the "//disk/" format doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open command prompt as Administrator

bind your drive again using below command

```
net use x: \\10.1.2.3\Share
```

again do the same in Command prompt without administrator (if its not bounded)

Comment: Yes, the network drive is already connected. The error is repeated.

Comment: do the same as administrator